# ViewPager with VideoView black screen

Tags: android, android-videoview

i have a videoview slider with ViewPager.
First video is working great but second video is only showing black screen.

Do you have any idea ? Also emulator is working great but real device does not work. 
i googleden people have some solution about for example adding the SurfaceView.

But it does not still work for me.
Can you help me ?

EDIT:
https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.p9ccfp46c
solved my problem.

Comment: Have you fixed black flashing on video start using given link in viewpager?

Comment: nope, but the problem is about android 5 codec problem. all video should be the same codec. eg MPEG-4